# Wordpress forbidden 403 on delete in production vs local environment

Tags: jquery, errors, rest-api

i build a system that allow the user to delete post by ID with wordpress API.
this system works fine on localhost, but after i uploaded the site to production 
i can't delete the post
all i get is an error message

> DELETE https://mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/student_list/6954 403 (Forbidden)

i don't understand what is the difference between production and localhost environment.
the code is the same and the nonce works as far i can see
the js file:

```
function deleteStudent(e) {
  let thisStudent = jQuery(e.target).parents("tr");
  jQuery.ajax({
    beforeSend: xhr => {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", programsData.nonce);
    },
    url:
      `${programsData.root_url}/wp-json/wp/v2/student_list/` +
      thisStudent.data("id"),
    type: "DELETE",
    success: response => {
      // thisStudent.slideUp();
      location.reload();

      console.log("student deleted");
    },
    error: response => {
      console.error("student was not deleted");
    }
  });
}
```

ths function.php

```
 wp_localize_script('student_management', 'programsData', [
        'root_url' => get_site_url(),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest'),
    ]);
```

the only thing i know is different is that the live version was upgraded to wordpress 5.3 and the localhost is on 5.2 - i don't think it's relevant

Comment: Are the server environments identical? Could it be that your prod environment simply denies any `DELETE` request?

Comment: Are you logged in to both?

Comment: no . i can delete posts. and yes i'm logged in as the same user

Comment: "i can delete posts" - doing this via /wp-admin is not the same as sending an http request of type `DELETE`. Can't check right now but I'm pretty sure, WP internally does not use this http type

Comment: if that was the case i wouldn't be able  to delete the post in my localhost

Comment: No. It could be that your production host does not admit requests with Delete method. Azure webapps for example, only allows Post and Get.

Comment: yes. this was the problem. i have changed the method from delete to post and updated the post status to draft and the post was removed.